# iOS adding image view at center programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, autolayout

I attempt to create a button panel with 3 buttons in two rows. Given it does not need to be flexible, I tried

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonPanel: UIView! // auto layout, aligned to the bottom of screen
    var icon0: UIImageView!
    var icon1: UIImageView!
    ...
    var icon5: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        icon0 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_smiley_gray.png"))
        icon1 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_smiley_gray.png"))
        // ...
        icon5 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_smiley_gray.png"))
        let icons = [icon0, icon1, ..., icon5]

        let btnCellW = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.width) / 3.0
        let btnCellH = buttonPanel.frame.height / 2.0
        for j in 0..<2 {
            for i in 0..<3 {
                let rect = CGRect(x: btnCellW * CGFloat(i),
                              y: btnCellH * CGFloat(j),
                              width: btnCellW, height: btnCellH)
                let cell = UIView(frame: rect)
                cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
                cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
                cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.85 + 0.15 * CGFloat(1 - i % 2), green: 0.85, blue: 0.85,
                                                 alpha: 1.0).CGColor
                buttonPanel.addSubview(cell)
                let ic = icons[i + j*3]
                ic.center = cell.center
                ic.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
                ic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
                NSLog("adding icon \(ic.image) at \(ic.center.x) x \(ic.center.y)")
                cell.addSubview(ic)
            }
        }
```

The button panel is drawn correctly with the cells, but only the first cell has an image, so the image asset is good. Other cells are blank. What is my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
ic.center = cell.center
```

That can't possibly be right, because the center of a view is in the coordinates of its superview. You are mixing apples and oranges. You want the center of `ic` to be centered *within* its superview, but instead you are putting it at the same coordinates relative to `cell` that `cell` has relative to `buttonPanel`! Thus, all the `ic` images except the first are _outside the bounds`of their`cell`, and are thus invisible.

Instead, figure out the center of `cell` *bounds* and put the center of `ic` there: i.e., at `CGPoint(x:cell.bounds.width/2, y:cell.bounds.height/2)`.

Comment: you are correct. I mistakenly think the center is in the screen coordinate.